# C# Generic Type Paramater, initialize class inside constructor

Tags: c#

I have this Generic Class:

```
public class ApiResult<T> where T : class
    {
        public string CorrelationId { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }
        public T Result { get; set; }

        public ApiResult() { }
    }
```

And I used it like this

```
ApiResult<myPropClass> someVar = new ApiResult<myPropClass>();
someVar.Result = new myPropClass();
```

as you can see here I need to define my Generic class after initialization.
`someVar.Result = new myPropClass();`

My question, is there a way to initialize class inside generic type constructor? something like this

```
public ApiResult(){
//init class
this.Result = new T();
}
```

**--EDIT--**

This is the answer:

```
public class ApiResult<T> where T : class, new()
    {
        public string CorrelationId { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }
        public T Result { get; set; }

        public ApiResult() { this.Result = new T(); }
    }

...

//use
ApiResult<myPropClass> someVar = new ApiResult<myPropClass>();
someVar.Result.prop = "your value";
```

Comment: Yes, there is. Add the `new()` constraint to the constraints for your generic type argument. This will then impose the requirement that any type being used for `T` must have the implicit default constructor or declare a public parameterless constructor (so that your generic class can then successfully do `new T()`...)

Comment: You can also use [Activator.CreateInstance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?view=net-6.0).

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace so it would be like this? `ApiResult<T> where T : new()`

Comment: @hijinxbassist, not good, as this trades the compile-time check (compile-time checks are good!) for a runtime-check (and therefore possible exceptions; is that still good?)

Comment: @vantian perhaps. I have to admit, from the top of my head i am unsure whether you would still need the `class` constraint or not...

Comment: @vantian Use `where T : class, new()` if you want to make sure `T` is a reference type.

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace: Yup, you need the `class` constraint.  All structs have a public default constructor, so they are all happy with just a `new()` constraint (and, I just tested it).  "Numbers stands w.Palestine" has the correct info